# Show that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $A\subseteq \cup_{a\in A}B_{\epsilon}(a)\subseteq U$ and $\{x\in X\mid d(x,A)<\epsilon\}\subseteq U$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

> Suppose $A$ is compact and $U$ is open in $(X,d)$ such that $A\subset U$. Show that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $A\subseteq \bigcup_{a\in A }B_{\epsilon}(a)\subseteq U$ and $\{x\in X \mid d(x,A)<\epsilon\}\subseteq U$

Now $U^c$ is closed with $U^c \cap A =\phi$ so we must have $d(U^c,A)>0$

So $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $d(x,y)\geq\epsilon \; \forall x\in U^c, y\in A$

Hence $\forall a\in A \rightarrow B_{\epsilon}(a)\cap U^c =\phi$

so that $A\subseteq \bigcup_{a\in A}B_{\epsilon}(a)\subseteq U$ [IS THIS CORRECT? Refer to this statement my $(1)$]

I think $\{x\in X\mid d(x,A)<\epsilon\}\subseteq U$ is an obvious implication of above statement? If not, please tell me.

Comment: Idea is essentially right, but it is easier to say that since $x \in A \subset U,$ there exists $r_x>0$ such that $B_{r_x} \subset U.$ The general guideline would be to use compacteness to find finitely many $r_x$ and choose $r$ to be the minimum of the $r_x.$

Comment: it is correct and obvious